# What does an for (;;) loop do?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I have seen a weird version of the for loop where only `(;;)` is used to write something, for example:

```
            for (;;) {
                System.out.println("dabarkai");
            }
```

My guess is that it behaves similarly like a while(true) loop. But if there are some diferences in their actions then your more than welcome to share them here.

Comment: it is sometimes also called `forever` (if the second expression, the condition, is not present (or it results in `true`), the loop will iterate - in this case for ever (unless terminated abruptly {Exception, break, return, ...})

Comment: For loop to create an infinite loop

Comment: Note that this is not any sort of "special form" of for loop; this is just a regular for loop where the things in the header -- declarations of induction variables, termination condition, post-loop update -- are empty.  Which degenerates to a termination condition of "never", no loop variables, and no post-loop update.

Comment: and it is exactly the same as `while (true)` - I *believe* compiler will generate same code

Answer (score 0):

It's an "infinite" loop, basically the same as `while(true)`

If you don't stop it manually (or by throwing Exception) it will run forever.

To stop it you can use `return`:

```
int i = 0;
for(;;) {
  i++;
  if(i == 10) {
    return;
  }
}
```